# Import and update power bi report with data gateway

Tags: powerbi, connection, visualization, data-gateway, onpremises-gateway

I already installed and configured a data gateway, pls how do I import a power bi desktop report and make it refresh changes accordingly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refresh a power bi desktop report using data gateway.

A gateway is used to connect power bi apps on power bi service and on-site data sources.

Read the official documentation for more info: [Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem)

Comment: Yes, a data gateway connects to data sources, by so doing, facilitates refreshing reports in power bi service.  I am asking because I've configured and imported data but still can't refresh